# OpenMP speed up Shared vector | Bitmap Image Processing

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, bitmap, openmp, shared-memory

I am making a program in order to convert a Bitmap Image into GreyScale. I am using OpenMP in order to speed up the process (Timings). I have done what you can see in the code and it went 4x faster than without parallelism.

```
void bitmap_aos::to_gray() noexcept {
    const auto max = std::ssize(pixels);
    #pragma omp parallel shared(pixels)
    {
        #pragma omp for
        for (long i = 0; i < max; ++i) {
           pixels[i] = pixels[i].to_gray_corrected();
        }
    }
  }
```

- Is there something I am missing when playing with shared vector?
- Is there a way to make it go faster trough the for loop?

I have tried already to divide the vector pixels into different sets of less vector but it haven´t work. Also I have tried something like this but is returning a weird image:

```
#pragma omp parallel shared(pixels)
{
    int nThread = omp_get_num_threads();
    int iThread = omp_get_thread_num();
    for(int i = iThread; i<max; i+=nThread){
        auxPixels[i] = pixels[i].to_gray_corrected();
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use the second code. It is not the proper way to use OpenMP. The former is fine and it should work well. As for the better performance, it depends of the `to_gray_corrected` function. It is certainly not optimized. I strongly advise you to use libraries like OpenCV for that since it is heavily optimized and it avoid you to reimplement the wheel. Theoretically, such operation can be vectorized and it should be nearly memory-bound on most platforms if your image layout is design to be efficient (certainly not regarding the code), even the serial version.

Comment: @JérômeRichard I agree that the second code is not the proper way to use OpenMP, however it looks algorithmically correct to me: so, why are the results "weird"?

Comment: "I have tried already to divide the vector pixels into different sets of less vector but it haven´t work. " No idea what you are trying to tell us... Do you mean AoS vs SoA? What is the underlying type of `auxPixels` and `pixels`?

Comment: Is `to_gray_corrected()` threadsafe? Can you show us this function if you are unsure? Is using `auxPixels` in the second code is a typo (i.e the codes are different)?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark The OP wrote that "it went 4x faster than without parallelism"